# Meaning of メリ and メリ子

Tags: katakana, manga, onomatopoeia, internet-slang

Context: in the manga [Dead Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Tube), a girl is being raped while being filmed. Among the comments on the video, some users wrote メリメリメリメリ and メリ子メリ子.

What is the meaning of the two comments? To me it looks like some internet slang, or is メリ just a transliteration of the English "merry"?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnqgY.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This メリメリ is this [onomatopoeia](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%81%E3%82%8A%E3%82%81%E3%82%8A), the sound made when a moderately-hard object (wood, leather, etc) is being cracked, ripped or torn. メキメキ is similar. I think what's being torn or broken is obvious from the context. Actually, メリメリ is a common onomatopoeia to describe this type of situation (try googling with メリメリと引き裂く).

メリ子 is not a word I know, and it's much harder to explain. Perhaps some peculiar wordplay is happening. 子 is commonly used in a girl's name, and 子/こ is also used as a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) (e.g., 判子, わんこ). In addition, こ is occasionally used to make a bit cuter variation of an onomatopoeic/mimetic word (e.g., ぴょんぴょん → ぴょんこぴょんこ, ピッピッ → ピコピコ). So, although メリ子メリ子 is probably a made-up word, it is working as a funny expression used to describe what's happening to this girl.